# Scala: How to find out which CanBuildFrom implementation is used for StringOps.map

Tags: string, scala, mapreduce, implicit-conversion, builder

I'm learning Scala by working the exercises from the book "Scala for the Impatient". One questions asks:

> The result of `"abc".map(_.toUpper)` is a `String`, but the result of
>   `"abc".map(_.toInt)` is a `Vector`. Find out why.

After reading "[The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html)", I think this is because of different `CanBuildFrom` implicit implementations chosen. How can I find out which ones are chosen for the above expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `show{reify{...}}` to get all implicits like this:

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>ru}

scala> ru.show{ ru.reify{ "abc".map(_.toUpper) }.tree }
res0: String = Predef.augmentString("abc").map(((x$1) => Predef.charWrapper(x$1).toUpper))(Predef.StringCanBuildFrom)

scala> ru.show{ ru.reify{ "123".map(_.toInt) }.tree }
res1: String = Predef.augmentString("123").map(((x$1) => x$1.toInt))(Predef.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom)
```

So `Predef.StringCanBuildFrom` with type `CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]` is used for `_.toUpper` and `Predef.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom` with type `CanBuildFrom[String,Int,IndexedSeq[Int]]` is used for `_.toInt`.

```
scala> Predef.StringCanBuildFrom
res2: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String] = scala.Predef$$anon$3@43b7a6fa

scala> Predef.fallbackStringCanBuildFrom[Int]
res3: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Int,scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = scala.LowPriorityImplicits$$anon$4@61af1aa0
```

Note that type is not `Vector` but `IndexedSeq`. `Vector` is concrete implementation.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. One question: How did you know the type parameters for the `CanBuildFrom` implementations? It doesn't show in your REPL as it shouldn't due to type erasure. Did you consult the docs too?